# schemacrawlar can't print out table name

Tags: schemacrawler

blow code just print out database name only,why?

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // Create a database connection
        final DataSource dataSource = new DatabaseConnectionOptions("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/target_db");
        final Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection("root", "password");

        // Create the options
        final SchemaCrawlerOptions options = new SchemaCrawlerOptions();
        options.setSchemaInfoLevel(SchemaInfoLevelBuilder.standard());

        options.setTableTypes(Lists.newArrayList("BASE TABLE","TABLE","VIEW"));
        options.setRoutineInclusionRule(new ExcludeAll());
        options.setSchemaInclusionRule(new RegularExpressionInclusionRule("target_db"));
        options.setTableNamePattern("*");

        // Get the schema definition
        final Catalog catalog = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(connection, options);

        for (final Schema schema : catalog.getSchemas())
        {
            System.out.print("c--> " + schema.getCatalogName() + "\n");

            for (final Table table : catalog.getTables(schema))
            {

                System.out.print("o--> " + table);
                if (table instanceof View)
                {
                    System.out.println(" (VIEW)");
                } else
                {
                    System.out.println();
                }

                for (final Column column : table.getColumns())
                {
                    System.out.println("     o--> " + column + " (" + column.getColumnDataType() + ")");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Strangely,

```
./schemacrawler.sh -server=mysql -database=target_db -user=root -password=password -infolevel=ALL -command=schema
```

will output tables and corresponded columns.

**Update:my configuration**

```
 schemacrawler-14.09.03-main
  Ubuntu 16.04 64bit
  MariaDB 10.2.1-MariaDB-1~xenial
  (I assumed mariadb may not be supported yet,so switch between blow two drivers,but neither works)
  mysql-connector-java-6.0.3
 mariadb-java-client-1.4.6
```

Comment: What version of database are you using, what version of JDBC driver, what jars are on each classpath, and why are you setting different SchemaCrawler options in code than in the command-line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I figured it out:

```
 options.setTableTypes(Lists.newArrayList("BASE TABLE","TABLE","VIEW","UNKNOWN"));
```

Caution:with MariaDB,table types is "UNKNOWN"